How to compute the derivative of action with respect to magnetic field?
In Magnetohydrodynamics, the Lagrangian density can be written as [1]:
$$\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}_0-\frac{|\mathbf{B}|^2}{2\mu_0}+\boldsymbol\Gamma\cdot\left(
        \frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t}-\nabla\times(\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B})+\mathbf{v}(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B})
    \right),$$
where $\mathcal{L}_0$ is independent of magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$; $\boldsymbol\Gamma$ is a Lagrange multiplier (also a Clebsch potential); the expression in the parentheses is a constraint imposed (magnetic flux conservation). Consider the variation of action:
$$\delta J=\int dt\int d^3\mathbf{x}\delta\mathcal{L},$$
setting $\delta J/\delta\mathbf{B}$ equal to zero gives
$$\frac{\partial\boldsymbol\Gamma}{\partial t}-\mathbf{v}\times(\nabla\times\boldsymbol\Gamma)+\nabla(\boldsymbol\Gamma\cdot\mathbf{v})+\frac{\mathbf{B}}{\mu_0}.$$
I tried to derive this by Lagrange's equation for fields:
$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\mathbf{B}}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial\mathbf{B}/\partial x^\mu)}\right)=0,$$
where $x^\mu\equiv(x^0,x^i)=(t,x,y,z)$. It is clear that
$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\mathbf{B}}=\frac{\mathbf{B}}{\mu_0},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^0}\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial\mathbf{B}/\partial x^0)}\right)=\frac{\partial\boldsymbol\Gamma}{\partial t}.$$ But how to cast
${\partial\mathcal{L}}/{\partial(\partial\mathbf{B}/\partial x^i)}$ and $\partial_i({\partial\mathcal{L}}/{\partial(\partial\mathbf{B}/\partial x^i)})$?
[1] Gary Webb. Magnetohydrodynamics and fluid dynamics: action principles and conserva- tion laws, volume 946. Springer, 2018.

Start by writing terms out in components. Afterwards, you may find patterns that suggest a more compact calculation.
